# Equivalent control in Android to WPF Grid

Tags: android, xml, wpf, grid, equivalent

I feel so dumb asking this, but I couldn't find the answer nowhere. I'm used to C# and XAML, but I'm getting started with Android Developement, so I'm new with Java and XML and I feel so lost.
What is the control that's closest to the WPF Grid?
How can I define it via code and XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html), which is explained in full with implementation examples in [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html).

Note that `GridLayout` was first introduced in API 14, Ice Cream Sandwich. If you need to support older devices, you can use the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) equivalent, [android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) which as its package name implies, supports back to API 7. You'll need to add the support GridLayout to your project by following [these instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res).

Answer (score 2):

Well, another possible solution is to use `LinearLayout` and then set `layout_weight` of child elements as required, but make sure to set `layout_height` of child elements to `0dp`.

For Example:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />

    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="SomeText"
            android:layout_weight=".5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```